# Visual proof of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left( \zeta(n)-1 \right) = 1 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, analytic-number-theory, alternative-proof, visualization

**Background**

Let $\zeta(\cdot)$ be the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function). I'm looking for a visual proof of the infinite series identity $$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left( \zeta(n)-1 \right) = 1. \tag{1}\label{1}$$

This identity arises in the study of [rational zeta series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_zeta_series).

While I've found a number of visual proofs of infinite series, some of which are described [over here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579579/visual-proofs-of-series-summations), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044022/are-there-any-visual-proofs-for-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2-frac-pi2), and another one in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294530/are-there-visual-proofs-for-the-sums-of-reciprocals-of-square-and-triangular-num), I haven't seen or obtained any for this identity.

**A Problem in Discrete Geometry**

I believe this question is interesting by its own accord. In addition, however, I hope any answers to it might yield insights into a specific problem in discrete geometry. It concerns the question of whether a square can be covered by rectangles of size $\frac{1}{k} \times \frac{1}{k+1} $. One can read more about this problem on the following [MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34145/can-we-cover-the-unit-square-by-these-rectangles).

The problem hasn't been solved yet. Approximate solutions have been generated, however. Below is an example of such an approximation by MO user Ed Wynn:

[image]

The connection with this problem arises upon proving equation \eqref{1}. We have:

\begin{align} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left( \zeta(n)-1 \right) &= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} k^{-n} \tag{2} \label{2} \\
&= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} k^{-n} \tag{3} \label{3} \\
&= \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(k-1)}  \tag{4} \label{4} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{k} \times \frac{1}{k+1} \right) \tag{5} \label{5} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+1} \right) \tag{6} \label{6}  \\ 
&= 1 \tag{7} \label{7}
\end{align}

We see that the connection arises in equation \eqref{5}, as the same terms as the sizes of the rectangles are indicated.

Please note that I am *not* looking for a visual proof of equation \eqref{6} -- \eqref{7}. This question is already addressed in the first one of the three MSE links provided above, which all consist of visual proofs.

> **Question**: is there a visual proof of \eqref{1} ? It can be a proof of your own making, or a pointer to a relevant paper.

Comment: I don't even have a visual sense of the zeta function.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Perhaps Hans Lundmark's answer to the following question can help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-ways-to-prove-sum-k-1-infty-frac1k2-frac-pi26-the-b/8516#8516